# Google Analytics Tracking - Extensible parameter (utme) not showing in _utm.gif request

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, dom-events

Inspecting `_utm.gif` I've determined the Extensible Parameter `utme` is not being passed. I don't see it at all when I inspect it with Firebug. I'm trying to track an event with Google Analytics - a simple button click.

The Google code in `<head>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);  //in reality, this ID is set correctly
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
  try {
    var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
    _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', ' + category + ', ' + action + ']);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
  }catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

The code I use in the `<body>`

```
<a onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'button', 'clicked');return false;" href="http://someoutboundlink.com">
<img src="http://some-image.png">
</a>
```

What am I missing?  Why aren't my params `button` and `clicked` being passed in the `_utm.gif`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is wrong. Just because you named your tracker variable myTracker it's not the internal name of the tracker. In your case you use a nameless tracker. And the correct way to fire an event for it is just calling `_trackEvent`.

```
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
  try {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action ]);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
  }catch(err){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  ALTHOUGH, I had to change the _gaq.push parameters to:  (['_trackEvent', category, action]) to get it to work. I had to remove the single quotes and +'s around the last two items in the array.

Comment: Fixed the syntax issue (which had been on the original but should now be fixed)

Answer (score 1):

Could be the quotes issue in your track event call:

Try:

```
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category, action]);
```

Comment: No luck.  Admittedly, I'm not very familiar with javascript's syntax.  Perhaps I should do I tutorial first.  The code, though, was copied straight from google's help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

My `onClick` was incorrectly spelled `onclick` in my real code.  My example above is correct.

It's the little things.

**EDIT**
My answer is incorrect.  See the accepted answer above.